# Covariance Matrix by Multi-Factor Model

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, factor-models

I have been trying to find literature for the derivation of the covariance matrix, following a  multi-factor model. I have had no luck at all, every single article I have found on the web already gives the formula $$\Sigma_z=B\Sigma_fB'+\Sigma_{ee}$$ But not a derivation of it, could someone please point me to the right literature.

Answer (score 5):

Let there be $n$ assets and $k$ factors in the market. We assume multivariate normally distributed factor returns

$$
r_f\sim \mathrm{N}\left(\mu_f,\Sigma_f\right)
$$

with $k\times k$ factor covariance matrix $\Sigma_f$. Conditional on the factor return, $r_f$, the return of an asset $i$, $r_i$, is normally distributed with mean level $\mu_i|r_f=\beta_i^Tr_f=\beta_{i,1}r_1+\ldots+\beta_{i,k}r_k$ and residual return variance $\sigma_{i,\epsilon}^2$. The residual returns between any $i\neq j$ are independent.

Thus, the unconditional covariance between some assets $i$ and $j$ are:

$$
\begin{align}
Cov(r_i,r_j)&=\mathrm{E}\left((\beta_{i,1}(r_1-\mu_1)+\ldots\beta_{i,k}(r_k-\mu_k)+\epsilon_i)(\beta_{j,1}(r_1-\mu_1)+\ldots\beta_{j,k}(r_k-\mu_k)+\epsilon_j)\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left((\beta_i^T(r_f-\mu_f)+\epsilon_i)(\beta_j^T(r_f-\mu_f)+\epsilon_j)\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(\beta_i^T(r_f-\mu_f)(r_f-\mu_f)^T\beta_j+\beta_i^T(r_f-\mu_f)\epsilon_j+\beta_j^T(r_f-\mu_f)\epsilon_i+\epsilon_i\epsilon_j\right)\\
&=\beta_i^T\Sigma_f\beta_j+E(\epsilon_i\epsilon_j)
\end{align}
$$

If $i=j$, then $E(\epsilon_i\epsilon_j)=\sigma_{i,\epsilon}^2$, else it is zero.

Let us now collect the beta coefficient vectors for each asset into a matrix, i.e. we stack the $\beta_i^T$ rows into a matrix:

$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1^T\\
\beta_2^T\\
\ldots\\
\beta_n^T\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can now trace out all combinations of $i,j$:

$$
\begin{align}
Cov(r)&=\begin{pmatrix}
Cov(r_1,r_1)&Cov(r_1,r_2)&\ldots&Cov(r_1,r_n)\\
Cov(r_1,r_2)&Cov(r_2,r_2)&\ldots&Cov(r_2,r_n)\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
Cov(r_1,r_n)&Cov(r_2,r_n)&\ldots&Cov(r_n,r_n)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_1+\sigma_{1,\epsilon}^2
&\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_2&\ldots&\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_n\\
\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_2
&\beta_2^T\Sigma_f\beta_2+\sigma_{2,\epsilon}^2&\ldots&\beta_2^T\Sigma_f\beta_n\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_n&\beta_2^T\Sigma_f\beta_n&\ldots&\beta_n^T\Sigma_f\beta_n+\sigma_{n,\epsilon}^2
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_1
&\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_2&\ldots&\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_n\\
\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_2
&\beta_2^T\Sigma_f\beta_2&\ldots&\beta_2^T\Sigma_f\beta_n\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
\beta_1^T\Sigma_f\beta_n&\beta_2^T\Sigma_f\beta_n&\ldots&\beta_n^T\Sigma_f\beta_n
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{1,\epsilon}^2&0&\ldots&0\\
0&\sigma_{2,\epsilon}^2&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&\sigma_{n,\epsilon}^2
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=B\Sigma_fB^T+\Sigma_{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you Sir !

Comment: Have been looking for a derivation too - Thanks you!